# Running command when word appears in log?

Tags: c, file, bash, find

I would like to know if there is any way to scan a text file and then run a command. I have tried grep getting nowhere. I have also tried the find . thing, it sounds promising but I can't seem to get a good explanation on how to use it. If you would like to know what this will be used for here is an explanation: I have an iPhone app that sends a word over http, the server side application is listening for the command and when received it runs a command.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have a server app that's receiving a word over http, where does the text file come in to play? Your question is very vague; can you edit to provide more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will cat all files that find finds that contain "needle" and will show their contents. Modify accordingly:

find . -exec grep needle  -q {} \; -exec cat {} \;

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you could `tail -f` the file, and pipe it to this script:

```
while read LINE; do
   grep -q word <<< $LINE && command_to_execute
done
```

But the best thing would to place this logic in the web server instead of parsing a file (the log file I am guessing).

**UPDATE**:

The above loop is expensive to run as grep is called at each iteration.  This one is better:

```
tail -f file | grep word | while read LINE; do
   command_to_execute
done
```